# Is there a way to speed up the smeltery's smelting process?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tinkers-construct

The smeltery smelts stuff... slowly...

Is there a means to speed up the smelting process of my smeltery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several mods that introduce items that speed up the tick rate locally. Examples include time torches and items similar to them. Now you want to put this next to the Smeltery controller.

Between Ender IO, AE2, and some nifty redstone, it can be fully automated.

Comment: Please provide sources for this. The previous reply has stated that it's not possible, and you say it is. We need sources to verify this.

Comment: I can verify this, I've never thought of using them for that, mostly cause I hate the dam things and think their cheap but still, technically, this would work. Great idea!

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot speed it up.

However, you can process more at the time by increasing the size of your smeltery, which is handy when you start automating it.

Comment: This. The smeltery gets more efficient the bigger it gets, e.g. a 6-level smeltery can process 1 unit of ore or 54 units of ore in the same amount of time. Lava usage is more efficient with large smelteries processing large amounts of ore as well.

Comment: Sorry bro, @Bearhiderug came in with a great thought.

Comment: my answer assumed only then Tinkers Construct mod.

Answer (score 0):

If you put gasoline in your smeltery tank, it will instantly smelt everything down.

Comment: I know this is an oldish answer... but can you state a source for this?

Answer (score 0):

For the real, there are.
At least on 1.12.2, I don't know about another versions, but you can use Pyrotheum. The smeltery temperature go from 1300 to 4000, similarity, your smelt speed will up almost 4x.

Answer (score 0):

TConstruct's smelting system has two steps: melting and casting.

The melting step can be accelerated by using a fuel with higher temperature. Using [ModTweaker](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/modtweaker), you can modify the temperature of a liquid, and register it as fuel:

```
val goldDef = <liquid:gold>.definition;
goldDef.temperature = 50300;
mods.tconstruct.Fuel.registerFuel(<liquid:gold>,10);
```

Casting time is defined in each casting recipe, and there is no uniform API to change that. However, since TConstruct is open source......

The logic behind casting is coded in the [class](https://github.com/SlimeKnights/TinkersConstruct/blob/1.12/src/main/java/slimeknights/tconstruct/smeltery/tileentity/TileCasting.java) `TileCasting`:

```
if(timer >= recipe.getTime()) {
  TinkerCastingEvent.OnCasted event = TinkerCastingEvent.OnCasted.fire(recipe, this);
  //And some other operations
}
```

Using Java bytecode editors such as [Recaf](https://col-e.github.io/Recaf/), you can edit your TConstruct jar file to change the above code into

```
if(timer >= 1) //Or higher if this is too cheaty
```

This essentially makes all casting processes complete immediately.